# 1 Nvidia 3090 or 2 Nvidia 3080s for a 3d workstation?

Tags: rendering, gpu, performance, memory-management

Currently I'm running very large scenes for particle animations / simulations. I'm particularly concerned about the memory management distribution of the 2 3080 gpus approach for these very memory intensive renderings, so I ask the following:

Despite the significant VRAM differences between the (3080 / 3090) cards individually, I was hoping to get a better understanding of the possible trade-offs between 2 3080s vs 1 3090 for viewport rendering and scene rendering?

I'm totally fine with conceptual answers to this, since the cards haven't been released for purchase yet.
And thanks a bunch for your insight.

Comment: VRAM could be extremely useful when rendering complicate scene. And double the GPU can not increase a single GPU available VRAM in general RTX, GTX card. Which mean VRAM is not extendable after purchase. If you got enough budget, I would strongly recommend single 3090 for the VRAM capacity. And if you want more computing power, purchase another 3090

Comment: Hello and welcome. The cards aren't out yet, we can't make any educated guesses about anything ye. Either way this is mostly a personal preference/budget dependent decision, which is not a good fit for this site. Try https://blenderartists.org